# Trigger Oracle - Cant capture the userinformation who change the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I was trying to capture the user who fires [dml-operation] in the table_name from any schema. While trying to do so when I wrote the following code its captures the wrong osuser.

## Code

```
 create ore replace trigger trigger_name
        after insert on table_name
        for each row
        declare
         v_username varchar2(20);
         v_osuser varchar2(20);
        begin 
        select distinct osuser, username into v_osuser, v_username from v$session where osuser in ( select sys_context('USERENV', 'os_user') from dual;
        insert into audit_table values (v_osuser, v_username);
        end;
        /
```

How can I modify this code so that I can address/solve this issue?

Note: 
I am using the trigger in one server, and calling from the other server. Is there any way we can store the user information of the calling server. currently, it is returning the user information from the trigger defined server.

Thank You.

Comment: What you haver should work. What does it capture, and what do you expect it to capture? Does it have the wrong OS user, DB user or both? Do you see anything different if you debug with `dbms_output` - long shot, but there could be a trigger on the audit table. Where are you inserting from?

Comment: Hello @Alex Poole, thank you for the reply, however, this is not working I think, its because, I am using the trigger in one server, and calling from the other server. Is there any way we can store the user information of the calling server. currently, it is returning the user information from the trigger defined server.

Comment: That's fairly crucial information that you should include in the question. Do you mean over a database link?

Comment: @Feullie'Tombee'-ksub: please edit your question and detail all servers involved (database servers, application servers, machines ...) and which  `os_user` you want to retrieve.

Comment: Yes alex poole. I couldn't capture the user info from develpment server environment, who does the dml operation in the table in another server( can be production env).

Comment: Do you have any control over how the DML is issued - could you for instance ensure that a remote procedure call is made first? That could then set package session variables that the trigger picks up later, perhaps. Messy though. (Being able to modify a prod env from a dev ones sounds dangerous too; making people do things directly in the prod env, logged in locally as themselves, seems much safer and easier to control.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
select osuser, username 
from v$session 
where sid=(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);
```

Comment: Hello @pifor, thank you for the reply, however, this is not working I think, its because, I am using the trigger in one server, and calling from the other server. Is there any way we can store the user information of the calling server. currently, it is returning the user information from the trigger defined server.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how a trigger could retrieve information for another Oracle instance using SYS_CONTEXT or V$ views. Maybe the other Oracle instance could use DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO ?

Answer (score 0):

use `sys_context('userenv','CURRENT_SCHEMA')` and `sys_context('userenv','OS_USER')`
to get the schema name/os user. No need to do any "select into" or declare any local variables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER
  INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO audit_table VALUES (
  sys_context(
    'userenv','OS_USER'
  ),
  sys_context(
    'userenv','CURRENT_SCHEMA'
  )
);

END trigger_name;
/
```

Might be worth reading the docs on sys_context

Comment: what does that mean ? What is "the problem" ? What is the result you are getting? Happy to help if you give me details about what it is you are seeing

Comment: Hello @Koen Lostrie, thank you for the reply, however, this is not working I think, its because, I am using the trigger in one server, and calling from the other server. Is there any way we can store the user information of the calling server. currently, it is returning the user information from the trigger defined server.

Comment: This information is not in your original question, how could I answer that ?? Check EdStevens answer below, I can't add anything to that.

Answer (score 0):

When an operation is executed over a db link, the "user" is the user defined in the db link, not the user that is invoking the db link.  For instance, database MYDB

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "MYLINK"
   CONNECT TO "SCOTT" IDENTIFIED BY "TIGER"
   USING 'YOURDB';
```

Now, when user FRED executes the following:

```
select empno from emp@mylink;
```

Then, in database 'YOURDB', the operation is being executed by YOURDB's user SCOTT, not by MYDB's user FRED.